# Customizing Dates on the Gantt Chart for Jasper Reports

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart, gantt-chart

In the gantt chart on my reports I have 1 year's worth of data. I'm only interested in seeing the month printed at the top of the gantt chart. [Jan-Dec]. However, the graph currently displays the Month and the year. How would I customize the chart to just output the month?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/), but [`createGanttChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createGanttChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.IntervalCategoryDataset,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) uses a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) as the range axis. Something like this should work:

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(
    DateTickUnit.MONTH, 1, new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy")));
```

Comment: I can use this in the ChartCustomizer, which gives me direct access to the JFreeChart object.

Comment: Ah, part of JasperReports; post back with your results.